# populate combo box from BindingList<Wrapper> and return the Wrapper itself

Tags: c#, combobox

Is it possible to do this:

```
public class ParameterWrapper
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Definition Definition { get; set; }
    public StorageType StorageType { get; set; }
}
```

and then use it in a `BindingList<ParameterWrapper>` to bind it to a ComboBox control like this:

```
private void PopulateDropdownBinding(ComboBox control, BindingList<ParameterWrapper> parameters)
{
    control.DataSource = parameters;
    control.DisplayMember = "Name";
    control.ValueMember = ???;
}
```

Where I have the "???" is my question. I want to return the actual Wrapper object. So the Display Name is the Wrapper.Name but Display Value is Wrapper. Can that be done?

Of course I could take the `BindingList<ParameterWrapper>` and stick into a `Dictionary<string, ParameterWrapper>` but I was hoping for a more streamlined solution. Ideas?

Comment: have you tried an empty string and tested what the value is when selecting an item?

Comment: If you don't specify `ValueMember`, I would expect the value to be the item itself -- the `Wrapper` in this case. What are you getting instead?

Comment: @EdPlunkett you are correct. Not setting the ValueMember at all returns the ParameterWrapper itself. Thank you sir!

Comment: Personally I like to stay away from doing it this way. If `ValueMember` is not set (or `null`), who is to say that it has the same behaviour in `WinForms` and in `WPF`? I'd still set `DisplayMember` and stick with `SelectedItem` in this scenario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave `ValueMember` unspecified, `Value` will return the item itself -- in this case, your `ParameterWrapper` instance.

Much less here than meets the eye!

Answer (score 1):

You could add another property to your wrapper:

```
...
public ParameterWrapper Self { get { return this; } }
...
```

And set your `ValueMember="Self";`

Another (IMHO, better) option is to leave `ValueMember` unset (`null` by default) and use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`

Comment: thank you for the answer and a nice alternative with the Self property but I have to give it to Ed Plunkett as he was first.